# Log in differentiation

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm writing my first web application that requires a user log in for security reasons,  but I've noticed that during testing, data input by one user can appear in the database as though it's come from another user.  This may sound very naive, but can the application sitting on the remote server get confused with who's using it at the time? (I know I'm not making myself very clear),  If there are two simultaneous users, how would the root application decide who's doing what?
I use a static class to hold membership data, so that it can be seen throughout the web app.  maybe there's something wrong there?
I've been writing desktop apps for a long time now, but this is the first time I've written an app where the 'engine room' is remote from the desktop.  Could anyone throw some light on what's happening please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your real code looks like but you said "static" so this is what I imagine first:

```
public class CurrentUser
{
   public static string UserName{get;set;}  
}
```

The above means that the UserName property is shared for the entire AppDomain, which in an ASP.NET app means the entire website (excluding other websites on the same IIS Server). So there will be a race to see who can set the values first, but the value will be read as the value of who ever wrote to it last.  Joe logs in, Jack logs in, Joe writes a record to the DB and checks the static value getting Jack's name.

The more appropriate way to do this is to set the [HttpContext User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) or the [Thread User](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx)** both of which are available anywhere and in any assembly that references System.Web. You'd preferably want to lean on the [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and Membership features as much as possible.  You can get away with storing names in Session but Session cookies are less secure than the authentication libraries provided in the framework.

** Thread user is available even if you don't reference System.Web, but only if you set the thread user when authenticating.

Comment: That is exactly what's happening, (and my code is exactly that).  I'll do some research on HTTPContextUser, and use that.  Please pardon my inexperience again, but is it possible to use this without all the tables that the aspnet_regs  utility hangs in the database?

Comment: Yes, use windows authentication. The user list would be stored either locally on the server or in active directory. If that isn't an option, there is an xml membership provider, although I wouldn't recommend it for production code-- http://aspnetxmlproviders.codeplex.com/ Also, if my answer is correct please mark it as correct, thanks.